# Salvar Modelos Relacionados (One to One) - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relacionamento

Tenho um Model **Info** e um Model **Complemento** que estão relacionados um pra um.

Os relacionamentos já estão funcionando corretamente, consigo puxar os dados e tal, mas preciso fazer um update e não sei como.

Atualmente eu recebo todos os dados no `request`, mas apenas faço o `update` da tabela **infos**, como eu faria pra atualizar também os dados da tabela **complementos** de acordo com a **info** a qual ela pertence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar essa questão da seguinte forma:

```
$complemento = Complemento::firstOrNew(['id_info' => $id]);

//requests...

$complemento->save();
```

ficou até melhor já que tive a necessidade de também criar o complemento caso não existisse.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho quase certeza que você pode fazer assim:

```
 $info = Info::findOrFail($id);

 $info->complemento->fill($request->all())->save();
```

Comment: ola @WallaceMaxters, até tentei fazer dessa forma agora, mas não consegui. De qualquer forma acabei arrumando uma solução melhor para minha necessidade com o firstOrNew